# Difference in fans on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows, keyboard, fan, overheating

I have bought a Hp Pavilion DV7 with Core i7 CPU and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on dual boot with Windows 7 alongside. Apart from the difference in battery life (although that's fixed with Jupiter), I have another problem with the fans.

On Windows my fans work perfectly and the laptop is cool, but it seems to overheat in Ubuntu. It becomes quite hot and it looks like my fans are not working under Ubuntu.

I think I'm having the same problem as [How can I keep the cpu temp low?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124511/how-can-i-keep-the-cpu-temp-low/149467#149467), but since I cannot comment because of the lack of reputation (?), I post the question as a new thread.  I think the result of the overheating is that my keyboard doesn't seem to follow when I start typing a long text.

It just freezes and types the last letter multiple times. For example: when I type the word freezes, it shows freeeee so the zes changed into eee...

Comment: same problem here.
Laptop becomes as hot as i can make tea in it.!!!

Comment: I have quad core AMD with dual GPU ASUS laptop, using proprietary driver I have no temperature issues.

Comment: install Ubuntu as an Virtual Machine

Comment: Come on, there should be a better solution than using a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a nvidia optimus gpu, install bumblebee

```
sudo bumblebee-uninstall
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

$USER is your username.

Comment: I have a AMD Radeon HD6700 Video card.